# Access outer variable inside Angular Promise then() function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-promise

Good evening everyone. I'd like to know how I can access an outer variable inside the `then()` of Promise in Angular 2/4's typescript. I am trying to accomplish dynamic form validation to check username availability through a Rest API.

Here `userService.isUsernameAvailable(userName)` returns a promise which works perfectly. The only thing I want an answer to is, how can I change those `i` values on `then()` and `catch()`.

```
static usernameAvailabilityValidator(userService: UserService) {
      let i = 1; //outer variable
      userService.isUsernameAvailable(userName).then((res) => {
        i = 2;
      }).catch((res) => {
        i = 3;
      });
      console.log("i is "+ i); // should output 2 or 3
  }
```

**IRRELEVANT BELOW**

**Below is not relevant to this question**: I'm adding code below to provide context to what I'm try to achieve. You don't have to read it and it doesn't add to my question.

My objective is to return a function that returns `null` or a JSON object for the validator, because that's how validators work in Angular 2.

```
static usernameAvailabilityValidator(userService: UserService) {
    return (control: FormControl) : any =>{
      let userName: string = control.value;
      console.log("current username"+userName);
      let i = 1;
      let response:{} = null; //here response is similar to i
      userService.isUsernameAvailable(userName).then((res) => {
        i++;
        if (res.status == 1) {
          response = null;
        }
        else {
          response = {'usernameInUse': 1};
        }

      }).catch((res) => {
        response = null;
      });
      console.log("i"+i);
      return response; // response is returned to the outside function
    }
  }
```

Thank you everyone in advance.

Comment: [async validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validator-functions)

Answer (score 0):

`isUsernameAvailable` returns a Promise because it can't return a value immediately after being called (because it for example waits for a network request). Therefore your `console.log("i"+i);` and `return response;` gets called way ahead of your `then` callback and before the variables got modified. For that reason your `usernameAvailabilityValidator` can't immediately return a value, you could instead return the Promise or use TypeScript's async/await feature (https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/async-await.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to Implement Async Validators for the same

eg -

```
validate(c:AbstractControl) {
    return new Promise(resolve =>
      this.accountService.getUserNames(c.value).subscribe(res => {
        if (res == true) {
            resolve(null);
        }
        else {
            resolve({validateEmailTaken: {valid: false}});
        }
    }));
  }
```

You can Find more on Validators on this [Reactive](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/reactive) & [TemplateDriven](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/template)